# Migrating from Flask-Bootstrap to Bootstrap-Flask

Tags: bootstrap-4, migration, flask-bootstrap, bootstrap-flask

I started developing my Flask web app using Flask-Bootstrap (which uses Bootstrap V3) but now find I need Bootstrap 4 features. After a bit of searching it seems that Bootstrap-Flask should do the job. It is a fork of Flask-Bootstrap for V4.

However there are no specific instructions on migrating an existing app. I assumed that I need to uninstall Flask-Bootstrap from the environment and then install Bootstrap-Flask. The instructions tell me I need to create a bootstrap/base.html, which I have done, but I'm now getting errors about bootstrap/wtf.html not being found.

The Bootstrap-Flask files do not include wtf.html (although the Flask-Bootstrap ones did).

I'm unclear as to whether I need to retain all the Flask-Bootstrap files that are not specifically included in the Bootstrap-Flask package.

Can anyone point me to specific instructions for this migration?

Answer (score 4):

I am the maintainer of Bootstrap-Flask, sorry for the late response. I just finished the [migration tutorial](https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrate.html).